# Users to B from breadcrumbs of A type of pages?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a bunch of product pages with missing breadcrumbs and I wish to see how the impact has been on category pages (since category pages are linked on product pages breadcrumbs) so basically I wish to have 3 dimension data as below:

- Sessions/users going to category pages from the breadcrumbs of product pages.

Can't find a way which is as close to accurate or reliable. Any ideas how i can measure that through Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a segment of sequences, inserting the pages with breadcrumbs followed by category pages. If you put an event on the click on the breadcrumbs it is simpler, otherwise you have to build a regex with the path of the pages of interest.